# How do I set the variables for setSelect to get a full preview of an image with jCrop?

Tags: jcrop

I want to have full preview for image, but it's giving me 70% of the image.

What should I do with the `x2` and `y2` variables for `setSelect`?.

```js
jQuery('#preview').Jcrop({
    minSize: [32, 32], // min crop size
    aspectRatio: 1, // keep aspect ratio 1:1
    bgFade: true, // use fade effect
    bgOpacity: .3, // fade opacity
    //setSelect: [0, 0, 768, 540],
    //setSelect :  [0,Math.round($('#preview').height()),Math.round($('#preview').width()/200),Math.round($('#preview').height()/200)],
     setSelect :  [0,0,Math.round($('#preview').width()),Math.round($('#preview').height())],

    onChange: updateInfo,
    onSelect: updateInfo,
    onRelease: clearInfo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the `div.jcrop-holder` with object inspector of your browser. Definitely its width is not 100%. It can caused by your CSS code so you should find the problem there.

If you see that the `div.jcrop-holder` has `style` property and the `width` is set you need to set `boxWidth` option. For further information see the relevant page of the documentation: http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Sizing_Issues.html